# Attach document to a record in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I want to attach a pdf file for a particular record in AX 2012 form.

How to do that?
Please let me know the step by step procedure..

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at document management. 
Here is the introduction
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa549988.aspx

Comment: @david..Thanks for replying quickly.
But, I have already gone through this.
I am able to attach a word file or template  but not PDF file.
Do you have any idea for this??

Comment: At what point in this step by step guide does it not go as expected? http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa571562.aspx

Comment: @david..  Actually i am not getting, how to attach a particular file with the record.

Answer (score 0):

Docuref to specify the ref. DocuActionArchive.add(..) takes the docuref and a path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/docuactionarchive.add.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/docuref.aspx